# Sql server 2008 r2 services won't start

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

We lost power couple of times and I suspect that the UPS didn't keep the server on. I checked the log and it shows that there were couple unexpected shutdowns. I was try to login to sql server database but It won't let me, so I did some investigation and found that the services path does not exist. For example

> the path to the MSSQLSERVER service "D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\BINN\sqlservr.exe" does not exist
>   in the server.

I only see Microsoft SQL Server folder but no MSSQL10_50... I tried to repair using the DVD no luck it keeps failing and says master database is missing in addition to other files.

Any idea how can I fix this problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: This question really belongs on [ServerFault.com](http://ServerFault.com).

Comment: Ok thank you. I will move it there